# How can I change the font size in Sublime Text for each file independently?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

When you zoom in or out Sublime Text, it seems to affect the font size globally. Is there a way of having Sublime Text remember the zoom settings for each file - very much like how Chrome remember the zoom scale on a per-site basis?

Answer (score 8):

You can update the font-size only for the current file by entering the following in the Sublime Text console (`View` menu -> `Show Console`):

`view.settings().set('font_size', 14)`

where you can replace `14` with your desired font-size.  It will even remember it when you restart Sublime Text.  However, it won't remember it when you close the file and re-open it again later.

What you can do though, is set a syntax-specific font-size, so that for example all html files have one font-size and all css files have another font-size. When you have a html file open, from the `Preferences` menu, goto `Settings - More` and `Syntax Specific - User` and enter the `font_size` setting and save it. Then do the same with a css file open etc. Note that it is not the file extension that matters for syntax specific settings, but the syntax highlighting scheme selected for the document that has the focus when you select this menu item.

Example:

```
{
    "font_size": 20
}
```